# Suppress Docker warnings

Tags: docker

On each `docker info` execution I see a warning message, says:

```
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

The solution is available (i.e. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342735/docker-warning-no-swap-limit-support)) , but I wonder if it is any option exists to simply suppress a Docker warning messages?

Comment: how about `docker info 2>/dev/null`?

Answer (score 2):

Check first whether docker daemon is using **rsyslog** facility under :

`/etc/sysconfig/docker` OPTS
`/etc/docker/daemon.json` CONFIG

Then edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, to discard this exact message :

```
##RULES FOR  DOCKER##
if $syslogseverity-text == 'warning'  and $msg contains 'No swap limit support' then stop
& ~
```

Restart rsyslog :

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

If there is a file under `/etc/rsyslog.d/*docker*.conf` ; then you can put the configuration directly there and restart rsyslog.

Be sure that the above lines are added before calling configuration files `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` under `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.