# Warning: No swap limit support in Docker when installed using diskbot

Tags: ubuntu, docker, swap

1. I have created custom OS (Ubuntu 20.04) using [diskbot](https://github.com/amoghe/diskbot) with LVM partition (OS (50GB) and SWAP (4GB))
   During the vmdk setup I am Upgrading OS and then installing docker into vmdk.

```
docker --version
Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996
```

```
root@ub20:~# free -hm
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.8Gi       875Mi       367Mi        30Mi       2.6Gi       2.7Gi
Swap:         255Mi       0.0Ki       255Mi
```

My `/etc/fstab` file content

```
# This file is autogenerated
# <filesystem>  <mnt>   <type>  <opts>  <dump>  <pass>
LABEL=GRUB_CFG  /grub   ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro  0   1
LABEL=OS        /       ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro  0   1
LABEL=SWAP      none    swap    sw                          0   0
```

Now when I boot up the VMDK using virtual box (Version 7.0.8 r156879 (Qt5.15.2)) and run "docker info" command I am receiving warning "Warning: No swap limit support"

I have tried editing grub file `etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

then reboot the machine

Ref : [Docker -- WARNING: No swap limit support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342735/docker-warning-no-swap-limit-support)

But I am still getting same warning.

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after editing the grub file?

Comment: Yes I ran the `sudo update-grub` command.